# how can i merge these two xml files using xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Please i want to know how i can merge two xml files into one xml file using xslt.
I have these both xml files that i want to merge into an xml file as shown in the expected output.I want to include the each node **Hn** from the second file to the corresponding block with same number in the file 1.

file1:

```
<Test>
  <R1>
    <Th1>
        here are some instruction.
    </Th1>
  </R1>

  <R2>
    <Th2>
        here are some instruction.
    </Th2>
  </R2>

  <R3>
    <Th3>
        here are some instruction.
    </Th3>
  </R3>
</Test>
```

file 2:

```
<test1>
  <H1>
    here are some instruction.
  </H1>

  <H2>
    here are some instruction.
  </H2>

  <H3>
    here are some instruction.
  </H3>
</test1>
```

and here is the expected output:

```
<test2>
  <R1>
    <H1>
        here are some instruction.
    </H1>
    <Th1>
        here are some instruction.
    </Th1>
  </R1>

  <R2>
    <H2>
        here are some instruction.
    </H2>
    <Th2>
        here are some instruction.
    </Th2>
  </R2>

  <R3>
    <H3>
        here are some instruction.
    </H3>
    <Th3>
        here are some instruction.
    </Th3>
  </R3>

</test2>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hello Franky, you have to make use of the document() function. Try setting up an XSLT and see how far you get. thank you, Peter

Comment: Hello peter, i'm not expert with xslt. I just started to work with xslt and i don't know more thing about it. But i will make some researches on google concerning that fucntion. Thanks already to give a trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I. This XSLT 1.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vDigits" select="'0123456789'"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vDoc2" select="document('file:///c:/temp/delete/file2.xml')"/> 

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <test2><xsl:apply-templates/></test2>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*/*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
   <xsl:copy-of select=
    "$vDoc2/*/*
      [translate(name(),translate(name(),$vDigits,''),'')
      =
       translate(name(current()),translate(name(current()),$vDigits,''),'')
      ]"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the first XML document** (file1.xml):

```
<Test>
  <R1>
    <Th1>
        here are some instruction.
    </Th1>
  </R1>

  <R2>
    <Th2>
        here are some instruction.
    </Th2>
  </R2>

  <R3>
    <Th3>
        here are some instruction.
    </Th3>
  </R3>
</Test>
```

**and having the second XML document reside at `c:\temp\delete\file2.xml`:**

```
<test1>
  <H1>
    here are some instruction.
  </H1>

  <H2>
    here are some instruction.
  </H2>

  <H3>
    here are some instruction.
  </H3>
</test1>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<test2>
  <R1>
<H1>
    here are some instruction.
  </H1>
    <Th1>
        here are some instruction.
    </Th1>
  </R1>

  <R2>
<H2>
    here are some instruction.
  </H2>
    <Th2>
        here are some instruction.
    </Th2>
  </R2>

  <R3>
<H3>
    here are some instruction.
  </H3>
    <Th3>
        here are some instruction.
    </Th3>
  </R3>
</test2>
```

**Explanation**:

Proper use of the "*double-translate*" method first demoed by Michael Kay.

---

**II. XSLT 2.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vDigits" select="'0123456789'"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vDoc2" select="document('file:///c:/temp/delete/file2.xml')"/> 

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <test2><xsl:apply-templates/></test2>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*/*">
  <xsl:if test="not(matches(name(), '^.+\d+$'))">
    <xsl:message terminate="yes">
     Element Name doesn't end with number: <xsl:sequence select="name()"/>
    </xsl:message>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
   <xsl:copy-of select=
    "$vDoc2/*/*
      [replace(name(),'^.+(\d+)$', '$1')
      =
       replace(name(current()),'^.+(\d+)$', '$1')
      ]"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Explanation**:

Proper use of the standard XPath 2.0 functions **[`matches()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-matches)** and **[`replace()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-replace)**

Comment: hello Dimitre, Thanks for this solution. It walks very well. But i want to know the purpose and the use of the variable name vDigits. Is there any possibility to get automatically the path for the file2.xml, so that i don't need always to store this file in c:\temp\delete\...? Thanks

Comment: @FrankyN., Yes, you can specify a global/external (child of `xsl:stylesheet`) `xsl:param` for this purpose. Such parameter can be set externally from the invoker of the XSLT transformation -- as this is implementation-dependent, you need to read the documentation of the specific XSLT processor you are using.

Comment: @FrankyN., The role of `$vDigits` -- it serves to find all the digits used in the element name. First we find all non-digits (in the inner `translate()`), then we strip-off all non-digits from the name -- in the outer translate. What remains is just all the digits that the name contains.