# How to merge two xml files using xslt generating text output

Tags: xml, xslt, merge

I already saw variants of my problem under 
[how-to-merge-two-xml-files-with-xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15194718/how-to-merge-two-xml-files-with-xslt)
or
[how-can-i-merge-these-two-xml-files-using-xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423701/how-can-i-merge-these-two-xml-files-using-xslt) , but these examples do not handle the text-output and also not handle a static refernece to'default.xml'.

I am trying to generate a C headerfile beeing generated from a defaults.xml that gets amended by an target.xml.

I am using xsltproc as xslt processor and would like to be able to do 
`xslproc merg.xsl target1.xml > target1.h`.

Meaning to have one defaults.xml file and different target.xml files

example defaults.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<defaults>
<ConfigParam name="F_SAMPLE_STRING">
  <value>{1,0,0}</value>
</ConfigParam>

<ConfigParam name="F_SAMPLE_INT">
  <value>40</value>
</ConfigParam>

<ConfigParam name="F_SAMPLE_X">
  <value>TRUE_DEF</value>
</ConfigParam>

</defaults>
```

and a sample target1.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Override>
  <ConfigParam name="F_SAMPLE_STRING">
    <value>"hallo"</value>
  </ConfigParam>

  <ConfigParam name="F_SAMPLE_Y">
    <value>TRUE</value>
  </ConfigParam>
</Override>
```

My own starting xslt looks like this, but does lack the merging/amendment part

> 

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="text"/> 
<xsl:param name="fileName" select=" 'defaults.xml' " />
<xsl:param name="defaults" select="document($fileName)" />
<xsl:variable name="defaultParams" select="$defaults//ConfigParam" />


  <xsl:template match="@* | node() ">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  
  <xsl:template match="ConfigParam">
  #define <xsl:value-of select="@name"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="value"/>    <xsl:text>&#xd;&#xa;</xsl:text> 
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The other examples I saw use a static target.xml or use both files (target/defaults) from static locations. They also do not output text but xml.
I am new to xslt and can not come up with a good merging identity pattern.
Please help.

Comment: What is the expected output in your example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to Merge two xml files with XSLT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15194718/how-to-merge-two-xml-files-with-xslt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/> 
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="path-to-defaults" select="'defaults.xml'" />
<xsl:variable name="defaults" select="document($path-to-defaults)/defaults/ConfigParam" />
<xsl:variable name="overrides" select="/Override/ConfigParam" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$defaults[not(@name = $overrides/@name)]" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$overrides" />
</xsl:template>     

<xsl:template match="ConfigParam">
    <xsl:text>#define </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xd;&#xa;</xsl:text> 
</xsl:template>  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This assumes you will be processing the `target1.xml` file and pointing to a constant `defaults.xml` file. The result here is:

```
#define F_SAMPLE_INT 40
#define F_SAMPLE_X TRUE_DEF
#define F_SAMPLE_STRING "hallo"
#define F_SAMPLE_Y TRUE
```

Note: with a text output, you don't want to use the identity transform template.

Comment: Thx, alot. Exactly what I wanted. The selective apply of templates to the node-sets and the setup of node-sets are the eye-openers.